# Calculating the convolution of $\sin(t)/t$

Tags: integration, convolution

So how would I go about calculating the convolution of:

$$1* \sin(t)/t$$

This will be a simple looking integral, however $\sin$ or $\cos$ are not defined for infinity and negative infinity.

Comment: See [Sine Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the convolution is simply the integral of the function, or

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \frac{\sin{t}}{t} = \pi$$

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how you get pi from that

Comment: This is a well-known integral and can be computed in several ways, e.g., Parseval-Plancherel, Cauchy's theorem, ...